# Linear map from $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{C}^2)$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, determinant, lie-algebras

I was trying to define an intertwiner between the alternating square $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and $\mathbb{C}$ to show that if $\rho$ is the standard Lie group representation, then $\Lambda^2\rho$ is isomorphic to the determinant representation $\det: \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})>G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

My idea was to define $\varphi: \Lambda^2(\mathbb{C}^2) \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$ \varphi(v \wedge v') = \det(v,v')$$
This seems to do the trick in all respects except one: I can't show that it is linear.

In general, we have

$$\varphi(v_1 \wedge v_1' + v_2 \wedge v_2') = \varphi((v_1 + v_2) \wedge (v_1' + v_2')) = \det(v_1+v_2, v_1' + v_2')$$
which can be expanded into

$$\det(v_1,v_1')+ \det(v_2,v_2') + \det(v_1,v_2') + \det(v_2,v_1')\ .$$

What we want to show, in order to demonstrate linearity, is that this in fact equals
$$\det(v_1,v_1') + \det(v_2,v_2')\ ,$$
i.e. that
\begin{equation}
\det(v_1,v_2') + \det(v_2,v_1') = 0\ . \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{equation}

This clearly does not hold in general, but hinges upon the relation $v \wedge v' = - v' \wedge v$.

Whichever way I turn the signs and try to expand $\det(v_1+v_2, v_1' + v_2')$, I can't seem to deduce ($\dagger$). I have hence resorted to

Comment: I don't see the problem. But you made an error:
$$v_1\wedge v_1'+v_2\wedge v_2'\neq (v_1+v_2)\wedge(v_1'+v_2').$$ The wedge product is bilinear, so the right hand side expands as
$$ (v_1+v_2)\wedge(v_1'+v_2')=v_1\wedge v_1'+v_1\wedge v_2'+v_2\wedge v_1'+v_2\wedge v_2'.$$ This should explain your difficulties.

Comment: In $\Lambda^2(V)$ there is, in general, no way of compressing $x_1\wedge x_2+x_3\wedge x_4$ into something shorter. But when $V=\Bbb{C}^2$ is a 2-dimensional space you can, assuming $v_1$ and $v_1'$ are linearly independent, write $v_2$ and $v_2'$ w.r.t. the basis $\{v_1,v_1'\}$ and then proceed.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150485/11619) for more calculations in the second wedge power. Matt E's link gives you much more information.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen for his help. Using his suggestions, we here show that $\varphi$ is indeed linear.

As the statement is trivial for $v_1$ and $v_1'$ linearly dependent, we assume they are linearly independent and hence span $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Thus there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $v_2 = av_1 + bv_1'$ and $v_2' = cv_1 + dv_1'$. We hence have:

$$v_2 \wedge v_2' = (av_1 + bv_1') \wedge (cv_1 + dv_1') = (ad-bc)(v_1 \wedge v_1')$$

And thus we conclude that

$$\varphi(v_1 \wedge v_1' + v_2 \wedge v_2') = (1+ad-bc)\det(v_1 , v_1') = \det(v_1,v_1') + \det(v_2,v_2')$$

Thereby proving the linearity of $\varphi$.

Comment: yes, this is correct. Tensor products and wedge products can be a bit tricky. I like to think about tensor products abstractly using the universal property etc. From this all the important properties follow. But the disadvantage is it is not very concrete/explicit perhaps.